# Add plot title after the plot has been shown in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I have been provided a Python function that creates 2 plots.
I use it in a for loop to make a lot of them, and I would like to set a different title for each of them, choosing it from a list. The problem is that I cannot change that function, so I need to add it after they are created.

I have tried
`plt.gcf` and `plt.gca` but both of them return a blank figure.

I copy the important parts of that function, in order to give better context:

```
def plot_calibrated_im(self):
    T, S = np.meshgrid(self.time, self.space)
        
    fig = plt.figure(dpi = 200)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_xlabel('Time (ns)')
    ax.set_ylabel(r'Space ($\mu$m)')
        
    ax.pcolormesh(T, S, self.im.transpose(), vmax=np.max(self.im)/3, cmap='binary_r') #
    if self.tX!=None:
        ax.plot([self.tX, self.tX], [-self.sizeX/2,self.sizeX/2], 'r-')
    fig.tight_layout()
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you trying assigning the results of your function to a vairable then assigning the title to the results, in this way:

A) my_graph = plot_calibrated_im()

B) my_graph.title("My Title")

C) my_graph.show()

Hope this helps.